# How do I add my timer formula back into Google spreadsheet for column of cells?

Tags: timer, scripting, google-sheets

We had originally gotten help from a Google developer a year or so back on how to add a timer to field when a certain cell is changed, etc.

Somehow, it was deleted or defaulted, but I was lucky enough to find the equation on one of our saved discussion boards. Can someone possibly help integrate code

```
if (sheetName == "Driver Status" && [4, 9, 14, 19, 24].indexOf(column) > -1 && row > 3)
```

into our spread sheet again?

Answer (score 0):

You can put out your JS code to be executed when the sheet is edited then you analyze the event object.

Here's an example from GoogleApps Script API documentation

```
    function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

You can then check if that certain cell was changed or not in if it was you can trigger your timer.